# Phantom Contacts created and modified

Tags: contact

This question is going to be a bit vague, because I really don't know what is going on.

There are contacts being created or modified in my org by users who haven't logged in in a week. There are no (active) process builders, workflow rules, flows or apex scripts that create contacts. What possible other explanations could there be?

Comment: Maybe try to start a debug log on users who create those contacts ? You should get more information about what is happening   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5

Comment: perhaps some automation/sync between user's email system (gmail, outlook, etc) and SFDC

Comment: Probably Gmail / Outlook integration is creating or updating contacts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've turned the contact sync to outlook off completely now. I'll let you know if that's fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have the 'Lightning Sync'  with Outlook. After disabling the contact sync the problem seems to have gone away.